# Build Dynamic form from JSON with Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui, next.js

I try to build a dynamic form on Next.js. I need to parse the JSON file and then draw the necessary components from JSON. And also need to use [Material UI library](http://material-ui.com) for styling. Could anyone help with some examples? Thanks a lot)))

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you share any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in this project.

https://github.com/redgeoff/mson

MSON is a JSON language to describe forms and there is an example in React with Material UI.
I have discovered it yesterday and didn't test it yet. But it looks nice